# Postion element on the right side of another

Tags: css

A positioning question.
I have centered `<table>` and I want to position `<div>` on the right side, so table won't move slightly to the left. How do I do that?
 [image]

I'm not very experienced with CSS and only know basics, so positioning always were a pain for me.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the table and div in an element, centered horizontally and `position: relative` and use absolute positioning to put the div outside and on the right.

```css
.center {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="side">div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!